# Parity 1.4.4 not running on MAC OS?

Tags: parity, mac-osx

I have 2 macs and on one the new parity is working and running smoothly but on the other I continue to get "**can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8080**."

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy,"
```

I have set the proxy and pac. in network, I should note that at home I have satellite connection and the office is cable otherwise both computers are the same running el capitan 11.6

neither parity.wallet nor http://127.0.0.1:8080/ will open

Comment: I'm running parity 1.4.4 on mac. Are you sure parity is running, what does the terminal say?

Comment: parity/906a34e69aec8c0d/v5.3-sec-overlayrecent/db/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable